How to make user in Django choose the workshop he added to make a service record for his own car?
im struggling with same problem for 3 days now, im trying to make my finish project which is some kind of online servicebook for cars we own, i have models vehicle, workshop, filter, servicerecord and i cant add servicerecord to the car i have added is there anyone who could help me?
Here comes a little bit of code i have problems with from forms.py and views.py:
class ServiceRecordCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        all_workshops = Workshop.objects.exclude(name="Other Workshop")
        workshop_choices = [(workshop.id, workshop.name) for workshop in all_workshops]
        workshop_choices.insert(0, (0, 'Other Workshop'))  
        self.fields['workshop'].widget = forms.Select(choices=workshop_choices)
        self.fields['workshop'].choices = workshop_choices

        
        all_filters = Filter.objects.all()
        filter_choices = [(filter.id, filter.name) for filter in all_filters]
        self.fields['filters_changed'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['filters_changed'].choices = filter_choices

    def clean_workshop(self):
        workshop_id = self.cleaned_data.get('workshop')
        if workshop_id == 0:  # Obsługa przypadku "Other Workshop"
            workshop = Workshop.objects.filter(name="Other Workshop").first()
            if not workshop:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Other Workshop is not available.")
        else:
            workshop = Workshop.objects.get(id=workshop_id)
        return workshop

    class Meta:
        model = ServiceRecord
        fields = ['workshop', 'date', 'mileage_at_service', 'filters_changed']
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }


    class ServiceRecordCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ServiceRecord
    form_class = ServiceRecordCreateForm
    template_name = 'create_service_record.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        vehicle_id = self.kwargs['vehicle_id']
        return reverse_lazy('service_record_list', kwargs={'vehicle_id': vehicle_id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        service_record = form.save(commit=False)
        service_record.vehicle_id = self.kwargs['vehicle_id']
        service_record.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

I tried to handle with it for 3 days now and all I got for now is this error:
TypeError at /create_service_record/2/
    Field 'id' expected a number but got <Workshop: Worksh1 (ALALALA)>.
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_service_record/2/
    Django Version: 4.2.11
    Exception Type: TypeError
    Exception Value:    
    Field 'id' expected a number but got <Workshop: Worksh1 (ALALALA)>.
    Exception Location: /home/kamil/.local/lib/python3.10/site-        packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py, line 2055, in get_prep_value
    Raised during:  servicebook.views.ServiceRecordCreateView
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
    Python Version: 3.10.12
    Python Path:    
['/home/kamil/workspace/car_care_log',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/kamil/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So how does the model looks like?

@willeM_VanOnsem Thats how it looks like for now
https://github.com/KamilKruczkowski/car_care_log/tree/develop
thanks for your reply, as i said from 4 days i cant handle this problem, i cant add service to the car i own, i tried to add workshop named "Other workshop" for every logged in user

ok i deleted old version of my createservicerecordform and made a new one, and it works for now
